# Unable to change url (Routing) in Angular 8 for window.open(url);

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to Angular 8.
In my localhost:4200 I have a link:

Click here to download my Plan (PDF)

I click on the link and my url is http://localhost:4200/#/LabViewerPDF but it still show:

Click here to download my Plan (PDF)
lab-viewer works!

I was expecting it to show:

lab-viewer works!

But instead it still show but the url is http://localhost:4200/#/LabViewerPDF:
Click here to download my Plan (PDF)
lab-viewer works!

This is my app.component.html

```
<a (click)="selectLab()">Click here to download my Plan (PDF)</a>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

This is my app.component.ts code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'test1';

  selectLab() {
    let url = `/#/LabViewerPDF`;
    window.open(url);
  }
}
```

This is my app-routing.module.ts:

```
            import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
            import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
            import { LabViewerComponent } from './lab-viewer/lab-viewer.component';


            const routes: Routes = [
              { path: 'LabViewerPDF', component: LabViewerComponent}
            ];

            @NgModule({
              imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})],
              exports: [RouterModule]
            })
            export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

This is my lab-view.component.html:

```
<p>lab-viewer works!</p>
```

Why is it after I clicked the link it shows the original value and the new value:

Click here to download my Plan (PDF)
lab-viewer works!

I want after I click the link to show only:
lab-viewer works!

Comment: Please also share your routing config and by default angular's routing strategy is not hash based if you didn't set it explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the window for this, you have to use the `router`. Try

```
<a routerLink="/LabViewerPDF">Click here to download my Plan (PDF)</a>
```

OR

```
  import { Router } from '@angular/router';
.......
  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  selectLab() {
   this.router.navigate(['/LabViewerPDF']);
  }
```

Comment: Sorry, am I suppose to import the this.router? Can you please provided me the import code for "router"?

Answer (score 0):

You are navigating incorrectly here:

```
selectLab() {
   let url = `/#/LabViewerPDF`;
   window.open(url);
}
```

---

This is how it should look like, your app.componenet.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-root',
   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
   title = 'test1';

constructor(private router: Router) {}


   selectLab() {
       this.router.navigate(['/LabViewerPDF']);
   }

}
```

---

Or even better yet:
Your app.component.html

```
<a  (click)="selectLab()" routerLink="/LabViewerPDF">Click here to download my Plan (PDF)</a>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

---

If your goal is to open it in a different window, then:

```
selectLab() {
    window.open(window.location.href + '/LabViewerPDF', "_blank");
}
```

Just saying this upfront, if you wish to download pdf's look into html2canvas and jsPDF.

If that is true i will save you time, since there are a lot of issues importing html2canvas. Import them like this:

```
   import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf';
   import html2canvas from 'html2canvas' //only works when imported like this
```

It will give an error, but it will work.

---

Good rule is to use this for your routes(optional)

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LabViewerComponent } from './lab-viewer/lab-viewer.component';


const routes: Routes = [
   {
      path: '',
      component: AppComponent 
      children: [
         { 
            path: 'LabViewerPDF', 
            component: LabViewerComponent
         }
      ]
   }
];

@NgModule({
   imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
   exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```